# Robot moves only forward for Twist msgs with angular velocity component

Tags: ros2, rviz, differential-drive, ros-humble, ignition-fortress

Environment: Ubuntu 22.04, ROS2 Humble, Gazebo Fortress. Installed everything from `apt` repos

I am trying to learn ROS2 navigation2 from scratch and have created a differential drive robot (same as [sam_bot](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2_tutorials/blob/master/sam_bot_description/src/description/sam_bot_description.urdf)) except that I want to do it in Gazebo Fortress as it is the [recommended version for ROS2 Humble](https://gazebosim.org/docs/harmonic/ros_installation#summary-of-compatible-ros-and-gazebo-combinations). This means that the plugins are defined differently as in [here](https://github.com/ashBabu/skidy/blob/ros2-ignition-gazebo/skidy_description/urdf/robot_test_diff_drive.urdf#L90). All the relevant works are made public in my repository [skidy](https://github.com/ashBabu/skidy/tree/ros2-ignition-gazebo). I think I have written a detailed [README](https://github.com/ashBabu/skidy/blob/ros2-ignition-gazebo/README.md) on how to set it up (for new users) and the [issues](https://github.com/ashBabu/skidy/tree/ros2-ignition-gazebo#current-issues) that I am having at the moment. The main issue that I face is that

- If the differential drive plugin in activated (commenting out the odometry and velocity plugin) in the [robot_urdf](https://github.com/ashBabu/skidy/blob/ros2-ignition-gazebo/skidy_description/urdf/robot_test_diff_drive.urdf), publishing to `cmd_vel` steers the robot straight even though there is an angular velocity specified. [video](https://github.com/ashBabu/skidy/blob/ros2-ignition-gazebo/videos/diff_drive_plugin.mp4)

The simulation can be launched as `ros2 launch skidy_bringup bringup_sim.launch.py`.

Any help on this would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* ASH, but I'm afraid that questions which are as broad as this are off-topic because answers would need to be too long. As it says in [ask] *If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much*. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so please take a look at [ask], [about] and the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) for advice on writing a good question.

Comment: Please refine your general query into smaller bite sized questions that will have specific answers.